# Can't import CSV (Chinese UTF-8) file into DB correctly using JRuby & "CSV"

Tags: csv, utf-8, jruby, cjk

Using **jruby 1.6.4 (ruby-1.9.2-p136)**

The CSV file has UTF-8 encoding.
Contents shown normally with TextMate.

Trying this but all I get is garbled text inserted into DB.

```
CSV.foreach(data_file_path, :headers=>false, :encoding=>"UTF-8", :col_sep=>"^") do |row|
    # parse and write to DB
end
```

**Some irb info:**

```
irb(main):001:0> puts "你好"
你好
=> nil
irb(main):002:0> puts RUBY_VERSION
1.9.2
=> nil
irb(main):003:0>
```

**These work:**

```
jruby -e 'puts "你好"'
jruby --1.9 -e 'puts "你好"'
jruby -Ku -e 'puts "你好"'
```

With the same settings, I managed to insert Turkish characters into DB. So, the problem is not like a Ruby to DB writing issue.

I suspect that the problem is with the CSV library, which is a part of Ruby since v1.9.2 (It used to be an external lib called fasterCSV) because I can output to file to console after I read the file.

I also tried inserting #encoding:utf-8 at the top of the code piece.

Answer (score 1):

There is a unicode encoding problem in "CSV.foreach" (Jruby 1.6.4 and 1.6.5) when CSV contains unicode characters. As a workaround you can use "CSV.open" rather than "CSV.foreach".

```
reader = CSV.open(file, "r")
reader.each do |row|
    # do something 
end
```

This bug is reported and seems to be solved in Jruby 1.7
http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/JRUBY-6266